# How to fit using a model, which has two highly correlated parameters?

Tags: correlation, maximum-likelihood, fitting, constrained-regression

I am trying to fit a dataset that depends on one observable, i.e. `x`. The model has two parameters that are highly correlated, of the form:

$$f(x, \frac{\alpha}{\beta})=f(x | \alpha, \beta)$$

For the fit I am using a gradient descent algorithm on a likelihood function. The likelihood won't see the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters per se, but only their ratio. Thus, the likelihood minimum will lie on the $(\alpha, \beta)$ plane along:

$$k=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$

for some constant $k$. In order to meaningfully extract both parameters, a measurement has been made that we can use to constraint $\alpha$ to $\alpha_0\pm\varepsilon$. Therefore we can, in principle use a Gaussian constraint:

$$L'=L(\frac{\alpha}{\beta})\cdot G(\alpha|\alpha_0, \varepsilon)$$

to update our likelihood. In order to verify that we can extract the parameters $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ from the data, we generate from the model $f(x|\alpha, \beta)$ datasets with random data. These datasets are fitted back, using the constraint on $\alpha$, previously mentioned. The uncertainties on the two parameters are obtained by inverting the Hessian matrix, evaluated at the likelihod's maximum.

**Expectation**

1. The distribution of the fitted $\alpha$ is around the $\alpha_0$, and $\beta$ around $\beta_0$.
2. The quantity

$$pull=\frac{x_{fitted}-x_0}{\varepsilon_x}$$

where $x$ is either $\alpha$ or $\beta$. Follows a normal distribution

**Observed**

1. The distributions of both parameters are centered around the right values but they are extremely narrow
2. For $\alpha$, the errors given by the fits are of around the right value, i.e. the value of the width of the constraint, $\varepsilon$.

**Extra information:**

The ratio $\alpha/\beta$ seems to behave as expected, it's only each parameter, separately, that show an anomalous behavior.

**Problem:** Why is the constraint giving me a narrower than expected distribution of fitted $\alpha$ parameters? Is there a better way to extract $\beta$, given the knowledge from the measurement of $\alpha$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.